# Analysing sonar with gradle

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

we are pretty much impressed with working of sonarqube with Java projects and planning to go for next level by analyzing Android projects. we have `Sonarqube version-5.6.6` and `gradle-2.8`. Below is my configuration added for our android projects build.gradle.

```html
 dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.1"
  }
  
  sonar {
    server {
        url = "http:sonar-url.com"
    }
 }

apply plugin: "sonar"
```

this is issue popping up when I run `gradle sonar`

`Could not find method sonar() for arguments [build_2gg1yf48v6l7ngh099813mf0i$_run_closure1$_closure4@61d34b4] on root project 'project name'.`

Comment: Check out [Integrating and Understanding SonarQube in Android](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/integrating-and-understanding-sonarqube-in-android/) for up-to-date detailed explanation on how to analyze code with sonarqube in android using gradle

Answer (score 4):

Hi i am curious why you decided to use an outdated plugin version, when you just start your gradle implementation. At [SonarQube Gradle Plugin Doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle) you find a detailed description how to actually use it.

Generally speaking for the new Gradle version, you need to:

- change the classpath
- change the task
- change the configuration

eg.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5'
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.host.url", "http://sonarserver.com"
  }
}
```

and you run it with:

```
gradle sonarqube
```

Additional notes:

- you do not need to put the sonar url in your gradle script at all. You could simply use a sonar-project.properties file in the directory where you are running the gradle task. in this case all your settings are easily reusable for different runners.
- you are maybe not able to set the property with `property "sonar.host.url", "http://sonarserver.com"`. In my project i strangly set just this property with `System.setProperty("sonar.host.url", "<sonar-url>")`. I do not know why, but i am sure there is a reason for that, and i want to let you know this.

Comment: as i try to improve my answers, and inputs, i am curious if this was at least helpful, or what you did to make it work